# How to display ALL of the repositories im working on in my github profile?

Tags: github, repository, collaboration

I am trying to display all of my github repositories so that when an employer enter my profile he can see all my previous projects, including those i was a collaborator in.

I know that there are pinned repositories, but it's limited to only 6 repositories. Is there any way to make all of my repositories be displayed in the same way? or in the same way that my repositories are being displayed on my dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to pin more than 6 repositories or gists to your GitHub profile.

The only thing I can suggest is making a personal website that displays all of your projects in the way that you would like and put links to it in prominent places on your CV/resume and online profiles.

Comment: I think that's what i'll do eventually, thank you.
your suggestion is to put links to the repository itself, or is there a better option?

Comment: You could use some kind of repository widget on your website. This was the first one I found after a search on Google. https://github.com/lepture/github-cards

Answer (score 3):

An alternative would be to use your GitHub Secret Repository. You just need to create a repository using your `username` including a `README.md`, and it'll be displayed on your profile page. You can use this to list all the repositories you want.

https://dev.to/puf17640/github-secret-add-a-readme-to-your-profile-25j1